# Read specific info from .json file in R

Tags: r, json

I have a few thousand .json files with sentiment analysis information in each file. There is a file for each ID. 
I want to bring certain information from the .json file into a df.
My issue is that there is often multiple piece of information per file that I'm interested in.

For example:

```
    PetID Entities Count Name
1  p00001       13     1   NA
2  p00001       13     2   NA
3  p00001       13     3   NA
4  p00001       13     4   NA
5  p00001       13     5   NA
6  p00001       13     6   NA
7  p00001       13     7   NA
8  p00001       13     8   NA
9  p00001       13     9   NA
10 p00001       13    10   NA
11 p00001       13    11   NA
12 p00001       13    12   NA
13 p00001       13    13   NA
14 p00002        2     1   NA
15 p00002        2     2   NA
16 p00004        6     1   NA
17 p00004        6     2   NA
18 p00004        6     3   NA
19 p00004        6     4   NA
20 p00004        6     5   NA
21 p00004        6     6   NA
22 p00006        2     1   NA
23 p00006        2     2   NA
```

Entitites is the number of pieces of information I want from each ID .json file.

The 'Name' column is where I want the information to go.

I have tried the following (hopefully this makes a bit more sense as to what I'm trying to do):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    file <- df[,'PetID']
    count <- df[,'Count']
    name[i] <- file$entities[[df[,count[,i]]]$name
}
```

But this doesn't work. (file is the .json file name)

I essentially want something that looks like the following:

```
 PetID Entities Count   Name
1  p00001       13     1  info1
2  p00001       13     2  info2
3  p00001       13     3  info3
4  p00001       13     4  info4
5  p00001       13     5  info5
6  p00001       13     6  info6
7  p00001       13     7  info7
8  p00001       13     8  info8
9  p00001       13     9  info9
10 p00001       13    10 info10
11 p00001       13    11 info11
12 p00001       13    12 info12
13 p00001       13    13 info13
14 p00002        2     1  info1
15 p00002        2     2  info2
16 p00004        6     1  info1
17 p00004        6     2  info2
18 p00004        6     3  info3
19 p00004        6     4  info4
20 p00004        6     5  info5
21 p00004        6     6  info6
22 p00006        2     1  info1
23 p00006        2     2  info2
```

Happy to offer more information if this doesn't make much sense.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT - INCLUDE THE DF CODE BELOW**

```
file_path <- getwd()
print(file_path)

file_list <- list.files(file_path, pattern = '*.json', full.names = FALSE)
head(file_list)

file_list_small <- file_list[1:4] # Just to simplify the process while trying to figure it out!
file_list_small

Pet_ID <- rep(0, length(file_list_small))
Pet_ID
entities_number <- rep(0, length(file_list_small))
entities_number

for(i in 1:length(file_list_small)) {
  Pet_ID[i] <- substr(file_list_small[i], 1, 6)
  file <- rjson::fromJSON(file = paste(Pet_ID[i], '.json', sep = ''))
  entities_number[i] <- nrow(summary(file$entities))
  max_entities <- sum(entities_number)
}

col1 <- Pet_ID
col2 <- entities_number
data <- data.frame(col1,col2)
data <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$col2),]
PetID_data <- data[,1]
entities_per <- data[,2]
data ; PetID_data ; entities_per

df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), max_entities, 4,
         dimnames = list(c(), c('PetID', 'Entities', 'Count', 'Name'))),
         stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

df[,'PetID'] <- PetID_data
df[,'Entities'] <- entities_per
df[,'Count'] <- with(df, ave(seq_along(PetID), PetID, FUN = seq_along))
print(df)
```

**I have also attached a screenshot of an example of the .json file - the circled information is what I'm trying to extract.**

[image: .json file example]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have you already read the json file? If so how did you do it? Can you specify what is `df`?

Comment: its basically: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(Name = paste0("info", Count))` what you need? no json import here?

Comment: Apologies.
I'll edit my OP with the full code for the df.

Comment: you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071854/need-help-pulling-json-data-onto-from-a-website-api) post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you question is a bit too complex to be answered precisely. I'll try to extract the essential part. From what I understand you were able to read your json files but it is not clear what your issues are exatcly.

suppose that you read the following json string.

```
>  file <- rjson::fromJSON('{"employees":[
  { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
]}')
```

you get the following list
    ## > file
    ## $employees
    ## $employees[[1]]
    ## $employees[[1]]$firstName
    ## [1] "John"

```
## $employees[[1]]$lastName
## [1] "Doe"


## $employees[[2]]
## $employees[[2]]$firstName
## [1] "Anna"

## $employees[[2]]$lastName
## [1] "Smith"


## $employees[[3]]
## $employees[[3]]$firstName
## [1] "Peter"

## $employees[[3]]$lastName
## [1] "Jones"
```

Then suppose I want to extract the last name of employees from the list and put it in a `data.frame`. First let's look at the structure of `file`

```
## > str(file,2)
## List of 1
##  $ employees:List of 3
##   ..$ :List of 2
##   ..$ :List of 2
##   ..$ :List of 2
```

So the first extraction `file[[1]]`, would give me the list of employees. Then we need to go through this list to extract the last names of each employees. We can achieve this thought `lapply`.

```
    ## > lapply(file[[1]],function(x) x$lastName)
## [[1]]
## [1] "Doe"

## [[2]]
## [1] "Smith"

## [[3]]
## [1] "Jones"
```

Then the next step would be to put that in a data.frame

```
## > data.frame(cbind(id="PET",lapply(file[[1]],function(x) x$lastName)))
##    id    V2
## 1 PET   Doe
## 2 PET Smith
## 3 PET Jones
```

or you could do

```
 d <- data.frame(id=1:3)

## > d$lastname <- unlist(lapply(file[[1]],function(x) x$lastName))
## > d
##   id lastname
## 1  1      Doe
## 2  2    Smith
## 3  3    Jones
```

Comment: If your json file is complex you might want to experiment with the first entry before.